# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{3} \biggl ( f(x+1)+\frac{5}{f(x+2)}\biggl)$ and $f(x)>0$, $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb R$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ is?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> > If $f(x)=\frac{1}{3} \biggl ( f(x+1)+\frac{5}{f(x+2)}\biggl)$ and $f(x)>0$, $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb R$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ is?

**Doubt:**

In solution provided in book they assumed that

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x+1)=\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x+2)=l$.

How can they all be equal?

Comment: You can show this from the definition, shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Oria: It doesn't look simple to me. Can you provide a hint?

Comment: The real question is why does $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exist given that $f(x)=\frac{1}{3} \biggl ( f(x+1)+\frac{5}{f(x+2)}\biggl)$ and $f(x) \gt 0$. Of course if it exists, we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x+1) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x+2)$.

Comment: Do we know anything else about the function f?

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \ell$ means "limit of f of "something" (not necessarily $x$) is $\ell$ when this "thing" $\to +\infty$.
For example : If we have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \ell$ then :
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x + 1) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x + 2) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(2 x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x^2) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(\sqrt{x}) = \ell$$
because :
$$x + 1, x + 2, 2 x, x^2, \sqrt{x} \to +\infty \text{ when } x \to +\infty$$

Comment: Gyus, TonyK is asking how you guys can assume the limit exists? If it oscillates or diverges, then the method may not work. For example, how can you guys the limit is not $\infty$? I think that $f(x)>0$ implies that $f(x)$ is constant at $\sqrt{\frac52}$ (but I'm not sure). I don't think any of you thought about it. If $f(x)>0$ was not there, then $f(x)$ could have been $\sqrt{\frac52}$ when $x$ is irrational and oscillate when $x$ is rational. I personally think that the question is probably not clearly stated. But there's a chance that it might be asking more rigorous answer. Who knows?

Comment: @KayK. It looks very similar to the reverse of the sequence corresponding to the Babylonian method for square roots, in which case both stationary points are repelling in the forward direction.  This at least implies that $\lim f(x)$ exists if and only if $f(x)$ is identically constant.

Comment: Another point: Without some more structure on $f$, we could define $f(x)$ relatively freely on $[0,1)$.  Then, the existence of a single non-constant converging sequence $(f(n))_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ would imply that once again, the limit exists if and only if $f(x)$ is identically constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$ means that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $M > 0$ such that
$$ |f(x) - L| < \epsilon $$
whenever $ x \geq M$. Suppose that $\epsilon$ and $M$ are fixed. Then $x+1 > x \geq M$, so by the definition of the statement $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$ it must be the case that
$$ |f(x+1) - L| < \epsilon.$$
So we obtain $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x+1) = L$. An identical proof holds for the limit of $f(x+2)$.

As an example, consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. We have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x+1} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x+2} = 0.$$
The idea here is that it doesn't matter if we shift the input $x$ by some finite value, since we are allowing $x$ to grow unboundedly large.

Comment: The real question here is: does $f$ necessarily tend to a limit?

Comment: That's a good question! I would try defining a sequence of terms $y_n$ such that $y_0 = f(r)$ (for some r in the unit interval), $y_1 = f(r+1)$, and $y_{n+2} = \frac{5}{3y_n - y_{n+1}}$ (this equation can be derived through algebraic manipulation of the originally given equation). From here, I'm not sure. Showing boundedness would be a good first start, and I've tried doing so using induction on $n$, but ran into issues. Perhaps one could show that the sequence is contractive, or cauchy?

Answer (score 2):

A proof if we assume that $f$ has a finite limit in $+\infty$:
Let $\displaystyle \ell = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$.
We have :
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) > 0$$
then $\ell \geq 0$.

1. Suppose that $\ell = 0$ : 
   We have :
   $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} \left(f(x + 1) + \dfrac{5}{f(x + 2)}\right) > \dfrac{5}{3 f(x + 2)} \to +\infty$$
   Absurd. We deduce that $\ell > 0$.
2. We have :
   $$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} \left(f(x + 1) + \dfrac{5}{f(x + 2)}\right)$$
   Passing to the limit :
   $$\ell = \dfrac{1}{3} \left(\ell + \dfrac{5}{\ell}\right)$$
   then :
   $$\ell^2 = \dfrac{5}{2}$$
   We deduce that :
   $$\ell = \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}$$
   cause $\ell \geq 0$.